# PHP order results coming from Facebook Public Search API

Tags: php, facebook

Can anyone explain to me how the "until" and "since" work on Facebook??

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=berlusconi&type=post&limit=10&since=1328263810&until=1328350210&locale=it_IT
```

I am still very confused..

Can I set a since and until and get ONLY the results from that period? Or does it work in a different way?

Also why it does return the newer posts before the older ones? I need to grab the older ones before and then go with the newer ones or my script will take forever to load all the results and order them by date...

Can anyone explain this to me, because in the Documentation there are very poor information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) there are four parameters:

- limit: number of posts per page
- offset: page number
- since: only posts after this timestamp (In your URL: 03 Feb 2012 10:10:10 GMT)
- until: only posts before this timestamp (In your URL: 04 Feb 2012 10:10:10 GMT )

By setting `since`/`until` you will get at most `limit` posts. You can paginate those results using `offset`.

You're query returns at most 10 entries that were posted between Feb 3th and Feb 4th.

There is [no way](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=69995) of sorting the result page in reversed order, however you can easily reverse it yourself in PHP.